# Select only a section of html table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I need to create a table in the browser from where you can select data and copy it out.
Also you can paste in data.
When you have table thats 10x10 you should be able to select 4x4 square from the middle and copy it out.
Same with pasting data in.
With HTML Table, when you select data, it will select from the middle, but if you move the cursor down or diagonally it will select by rows.

Example of how selecting should work is similar to [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/examples?manual-resize&manual-move&conditional-formatting&context-menu&filters&dropdown-menu&headers)

Ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Just an idea, but you could have a 'mouseover' event on each td element. Each td element would have a i and j value indicating their height and width on the table. When selecting, you could get the starting index (i_init and j_init) and the ending index (i_final and j_final) subtract the two to get the width and the height and add that to i_init and j_init to get the full box. Then see which values (i and j) fall under the box and highlight them or something. If you wanted to be even more fancy, you could get all of the outer edges based on min and max (i and j) and draw a border on them

Answer (score 1):

I decided to mess with it a little bit and came up with this. It is not perfect, but you can get the gist of what I am trying to do:

```js
var i_init = -1;
var j_init = -1;
var i_final = -1;
var j_final = -1;
var clicked = false;
var tableRows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
  var tableElements = tableRows[i].children;
  for (let j = 0; j < tableElements.length; j++) {
    tableElements[j].classList.add(i);
    tableElements[j].classList.add(j);
    tableElements[j].addEventListener('mouseover', OnMouseoverEvent);
    tableElements[j].addEventListener('click', ClickEvent)
  }
}

function UpdateTable() {
  var tableElements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (let z = 0; z < tableElements.length; z++) {
    let i = tableElements[z].classList[0];
    let j;
    if (tableElements[z].classList.length == 1) {
      j = i;
    } else {
      j = tableElements[z].classList[1];
    }

    let i_compare = (i >= i_init && i <= i_final);
    let j_compare = (j >= j_init && j <= j_final);

    if (i_final < i_init) {
      // backwards i
      i_compare = (i <= i_init && i >= i_final);
    }

    if (j_final < j_init) {
      // backwards j
      j_compare = (j <= j_init && j >= j_final);
    }

    if (i_compare && j_compare) {
      tableElements[z].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    } else {
      tableElements[z].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }

  }
}

function ClickEvent() {
  let i = this.classList[0];
  let j;
  if (this.classList.length == 1) {
    j = i;
  } else {
    j = this.classList[1];
  }

  i_init = i;
  j_init = j;
  clicked = true;
}

function OnMouseoverEvent() {
  if (!clicked) {
    return;
  }

  let i = this.classList[0];
  let j;
  if (this.classList.length == 1) {
    j = i;
  } else {
    j = this.classList[1];
  }

  i_final = i;
  j_final = j;

  UpdateTable();
}
```

```css
.table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```